# what is "::" symbol and where I can get more details on it?

Tags: java, lambda, rx-java

I frequently come across this in some RxJava example ?

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
      subscriber.onNext("Hello World!");
      subscriber.onCompleted();
}).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html

Comment: @GAlexMES No, it's a method reference.

Comment: @shmosel It is a method reference yes. But a method reference is a Lambda expression. Have a look to the Oracle documentation: 
__Method references enable you to do this; they are compact, easy-to-read lambda expressions for methods that already have a name.__

Comment: @GAlexMES I stand corrected.

Comment: @GAlexMES  - thank you for quick  respond and pointers, somehow I was not able to do google or so by "::" :)

Comment: @shmosel  - thank a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a Method Reference.

See: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html